# Escaping ampersands input by users through text fields?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, user-input, escaping

Like almost all apps today, I have users who enter various information through standard text inputs.  My app is running on Rails.

It's a no-brainer to escape ampersands that I include as part of the site copy, etc.  But how do I escape an ampersand that is dynamically input by a user?  Currently, it's breaking my frontend validation.

Comment: "Escape" them for what purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you display the values you need to replace certain characters with HTML entities. Those characters are:

```
& : &amp;
< : &lt;
> : &gt;
" : &quot;
```

Perhaps there is a HtmlEncode function that you can use for that, otherwise you can use plain string operations. Pseudo code:

```
output replace(replace(replace(replace(text, "&", "&amp"), "<", "&lt;"), ">", "&gt;", """", "&quot;")
```

Edit:
I found that you can use the html_escape() function:

```
<%=html_escape @text%>
```

Or short:

```
<%=h @text%>
```

Comment: +1 `h` is the Rails way to HTML-escape in a template. **You must always use this!** It's not just a matter of making ampersands look right; if you output text content into HTML without escaping it you've got a cross-site-scripting security hole.

Comment: Follow up tip for other nubes reading this later.  In my particular situation, the text was hyperlinked.  I'm using the link_to method.  If you try doing <%=h link_to url, url %>, then your url will get printed out on the screen.  The way to do it is like this: <%=link_to (h(url), url) %>